# GET request result to CORS error in Lumen 8

Tags: laravel, axios, lumen, lumen-8

I have this CORS problem when Axios sending `GET` HTTP to my Lumen app, sending `POST` HTTP seems fine. I have this middleware who's handling the CORS, below is the code

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class CorsMiddleware{
     /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
        {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

then added to `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class, // cors middleware
]);
```

with a `POST` request, everything is working but when doing a `GET` request, a CORS error occurs. Any help, ideas are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

My frontend app is running on `http://localhost:3000` (NUXT) and the Lumen app is running on `http://localhost:8000`

Below image is the screenshot of the error.
[image]

Comment: can you share CORS error message?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: This happened to be because lumen does not allow OPTIONS method, so we need to explicitly add that.

Comment: @AnkitJindal can you guide me how to add it?

Comment: @JuliverGalleto Please mark which solution works for you so that it helps others facing similar problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumen does not allow `OPTIONS` method and will return status response `405 MethodNotAllowed`, so we need to explicitly add it to routes.

**Modify `ServiceProvider.php`:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $request = app('request');

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        if($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS')  {
            app()->options($request->path(), function () {
                return response('OK',200)
                    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
                    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Origin');                    
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**CorsMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Reference [cors tutorial](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: Thank dear, but this solution DID NOT work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution to this problem can be:

**Create `CatchAllOptionsRequestsProvider.php` in `App\Providers` directory**

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * If the incoming request is an OPTIONS request
 * we will register a handler for the requested route
 */
class CatchAllOptionsRequestsProvider extends ServiceProvider {
  public function register()
  {
    $request = app('request');
    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
    {
      app()->options($request->path(), function() { return response('', 200); });
    }
  }
}
```

**CorsMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //Intercepts OPTIONS requests
        if($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = response('', 200);
        } else {
            // Pass the request to the next middleware
            $response = $next($request);
        }

        // Adds headers to the response
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        // Sends it
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**Add below code in `bootstrap/app.php`**

```
$app->middleware([
   App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class
]);

$app->register(App\Providers\CatchAllOptionsRequestsProvider::class);
```